# Can probing an EEPROM with a multimeter corrupt the data?

Tags: multimeter, eeprom, error, testing

Say there's an EEPROM on a board and you happen to try probing the pin one by one with a multimeter, is there a good chance that the sequence of probing the pins must have overwritten (thus corrupt) the data?

I always thought it was fairly safe as for EEPROMS, from what I've skimmed through, the writing happens in hundreds of kilohertz or above.

I was using the continuity tester in my multimeter that tests at around 0.4V.

Comment: The most convoluted, unlikely scenario I can come up with is an application where the host is continuously trying to write to the EEPROM and you accidentally de-assert they write protect pin. But that's incredibly specific (and silly) so like everyone else said, I don't think you have much to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

No, a multimeter putting out 400 mV shouldn't be able to erase or write a typical EEPROM.

If you observed corruption after poking at the EEPROM with a meter, it was probably due to static electricity on you or the meter.  You can easily get charged up to a few 100 V without even being aware of it.  Since your total capacitance to elsewhere is quite low, the total charge it takes is also low, and you may not even notice when you discharge yourself against something grounded.

Most ICs have diodes and other protection circuitry to be able to deal with some static discharges, but of course these only go so far.  Most current EEPROMs store data as tiny charges trapped on the gates of FETs by a insulating layer of basically glass.  These charges are very tiny, and a good zap to the chip can make a mess.

Answer (score 0):

OK, another big dumb brain fart. Thank you PeterJ for answering, though it was curious that you would delete your answer immediately.

A continuity tester is basically shorting the nodes to test for shorts... It wasn't a problem with EEPROM, but with the fact of probing it while powered on (<- ok for most of the time) AND testing for shorts.

I've made too many mistakes tonight (including spilling solvent on my only working multimeter), so I should probably hit the sack now before I do any more damage.

Though, if anybody have any suggestions as to what might've happened or any general tips, please feel free to post.

Comment: I'm not sure for continuity a meter would present as a short, unlike measuring higher current it could (and probably would) use a much larger shunt resistance, that's why I deleted the answer I wandered off before noticing you'd added it was in continuity mode.

Comment: I'm really missing the software world... Here in the world of hardware,  if you make a mistake (be it prototyping, testing and specially, specially learning) a mistake actually cost you dollars. In software, all you lose is time and effort.

Comment: @PeterJ: I don't care. I'm mourning a loss of another equipment (not the multimeter). It was just $12, but I still care for it.

Comment: Well, if you think about it (which is obviously something I wasn't doing when I tested for continuity). No one, I think, would design a continuity tester that tests live circuits. From a general theoretical standpoint you won't be able to tell if the path is shorted or maybe it's components are energized. So I'm pretty I'm the one that screwed up.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering why you'd want to check continuity across pins on an EEPROM ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use multi-meter to work out the pinouts for motor vehicle ECU's, which have EPROM and EEPROM chips. Never had any issue, even with infineon tri-core. The only way I know of that damages them, is using the incorrect voltage and current when trying to bdm flash or boot mode.